# Permissions issues with mounting remote server into a specific folder

Tags: mount, permissions, sshfs

I'm doing the following to mount a remote server to a specific path on my server:

```
sshfs user@remoteserver.com:/backup/folder/ /home/myuser/server-backups/
```

However when I mount the server the folder permissions change (they become 700), and when I test my rsnapshot.conf file I get the following error:

```
snapshot_root /home/myuser/server-backups/ - snapshot_root exists \
         but is not readable
```

What am I doing wrong ? should I mount the remote server with another user ?

Comment: Cross-posted at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20621/permissions-issues-with-mounting-remote-server-into-a-specific-folder), [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/permissions-issues-with-mounting-remote-server-into-a-specific-folder) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/220129/permissions-issues-with-mounting-remote-server-into-a-specific-folder). Please hyperlink your questions when you cross-post so that people can find all answers, and don't waste time posting similar answer independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FUSE has options to control who has access to the files. I'm guessing you want `sshfs -o allow_other`.

Comment: ok thanks. One more question, Will the remote server be mounted forever ? I mean, until reboot ?

Comment: Uhm it worked with allow_root instead. But then I got permissions error with rsnapshot tool.. but this is not related to this question.

Comment: @Patrick: As with any mount, it will remain mounted until you unmount it, or of course until a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is a folder with restricted access, e.g. only access for certain users, sshfs can fail to see that one of the IDs in that group belongs to the user that mounted the drive.

You just have to add the option "-o defer_permissions", e.g.

```
sshfs -o defer_permissions user@remoteserver.com:/backup/folder/ /home/myuser/server-backups/
```

More information can be found here: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options#default_permissions-and-defer_permissions?